# Applying a function to a dataframe to trim empty columns within a list environment R

Tags: r

I am a naive user of R and am attempting to come to terms with the 'apply' series of functions which I now need to use due to the complexity of the data sets.

I have large, ragged, data frame that I wish to reshape before conducting a sequence of regression analyses. It is further complicated by having interlaced rows of descriptive data(characters).

My approach to date has been to use a factor to split the data frame into sets with equal row lengths (i.e. a list), then attempt to remove the trailing empty columns, make two new, matching lists, one of data and one of chars and then use reshape to produce a common column number, then recombine the sets in each list.  e.g. a simplified example:

```
myDF <- as.data.frame(rbind(c("v1",as.character(1:10)),

            c("v1",letters[1:10]),

                c("v2",c(as.character(1:6),rep("",4))),

                    c("v2",c(letters[1:6], rep("",4)))))

myDF[,1] <- as.factor(myDF[,1])

myList <- split(myDF, myDF[,1])

myList[[1]]
```

I can remove the empty columns for an individual set and can split the data frame into two sets from the interlacing rows but have been stumped with the syntax in writing a function to apply the following function to the list - though 'lapply' with 'seq_along' should do it?

Thus for the individual set:

```
DF <- myList[[2]]

DF <- DF[,!sapply(DF, function(x) all(x==""))]

DF
```

(from an earlier answer to a similar, but simpler example on this site).  I have a large data set and would like an elegant solution (I could use a loop but that would not use the capabilities of R effectively). Once I have done that I ought to be able to use the same rationale to reshape the frames and then recombine them.

regards

jac

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 lapply(split(myDF, myDF$V1), function(x) x[!colSums(x=='')])
```